# How to grant access to manage other member into the YouTube API project

Tags: youtube-api

I have a few API projects and would like to add a few team members to manage the project. Currently they can't see the project, I'm sure there should be an option but couldn't find it. Appreciate any help.

Comment: This seems like a great start on an interesting question! Do you mind sharing what you have already tried and maybe add some tags to your question to help increase the visibility of this problem to those that might be able to help? Try adding a tag to let people know what language or tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Found it

https://console.developers.google.com/

IAM&Admin --> Manage Resource then slsect the project and add